# Loading two different AJAX requests on two different pages

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I have a wordpress website where I need two separate AJAX requests, they each pull in different parts. However it only pulls in ONE of the AJAX requests on both pages even with specific IF page statements that technically should bar them from one another.

AJAX works on both pages it's being called on, however both pages are sharing the *SAME* AJAX call instead of their own separate call despite my efforts.

How can I can front-page.php to just call it's SPECIFIC AJAX call and category.php to just call it's own? Right now I have the code I feel should be doing that but only `cat_loadmore_posts` loads on both pages.

**front-page.php**

```
<?php
$current_page = max( 1, get_query_var( 'paged' ) );
$the_query = new WP_Query( array(
    'cat'            => 5,
    'post_type'      => 'post',
    'posts_per_page' => 9,
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'paged'          => $current_page,
) );

$_SESSION['count'] = 1;
wp_localize_script( 'my_loadmore', 'misha_loadmore_params', array(
    'ajaxurl'      => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php', 'relative' ),
    'posts'        => json_encode( $the_query->query_vars ),
    'current_page' => $current_page,
    'max_page'     => $the_query->max_num_pages
) );
?>

<div id="main" class="container-fluid">
    <?php if ($the_query->have_posts()) : ?>
        <?php $count = 0; ?>
        <?php while ($the_query->have_posts()) : $the_query->the_post(); get_template_part( 'parts/content', get_post_format() ); ?>
        <?php $count++; $_SESSION['count']=$_SESSION['count']+1; ?>

<?php if ($count == 8 && is_active_sidebar('seriesbar2') ) : ?>
     <div class="post">
        <?php dynamic_sidebar('sidebar'); ?>
     </div>
<?php endif; ?>

<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
</div><!-- END CONTAINER -->
```

**category.php**

```
<?php
    $current_page = max( 1, get_query_var( 'paged' ) );
    $cat_query = new WP_Query( array(
        'posts_per_page' => 5, 
        'post_type'      => 'post',
        'category' => 14, 
        'post_status'=>'publish',
        'paged' => $current_page, 
        'order'=>'DESC' 
    ) );

    $_SESSION['count'] = 1;
    wp_localize_script( 'cat_loadmore', 'cat_loadmore_params', array(
        'ajaxurl'      => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php', 'relative' ),
        'posts'        => json_encode( $cat_query->query_vars ),
        'current_page' => $current_page,
        'max_page'     => $cat_query->max_num_pages
    ) );        
?>

<div id="catfeed" class="container feed-container">     
<?php if ($cat_query->have_posts()) : ?>
    <?php $count = 0; ?>
    <?php while ($cat_query->have_posts()) : $cat_query->the_post(); get_template_part( 'parts/categorycontent', get_post_format() ); ?>
    <?php $count++; $_SESSION['count']=$_SESSION['count']+1; ?>
<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
</div><!-- END CONTAINER -->
```

**myloadmore.js - the AJAX call that doesn't work once I added the catloadmore.js - worked previously**

```
jQuery(function($){
    var canBeLoaded = true,
        bottomOffset = 1300; 

    $(window).scroll(function(){
        if ( misha_loadmore_params.current_page >= misha_loadmore_params.max_page ) {
            return;
        }
        var data = {
            'action': 'loadmore',
            'query': misha_loadmore_params.posts,
            'page' : misha_loadmore_params.current_page
        };
        if( $(document).scrollTop() > ( $(document).height() - bottomOffset ) && canBeLoaded == true ){
            $.ajax({
                url : misha_loadmore_params.ajaxurl,
                data: data,
                type: 'POST',
                beforeSend: function( xhr ){
                    canBeLoaded = false;
                },
                success:function(data){
                    if( data ) {
                        $('#main').find('div.post:last-of-type').after( data );
                        canBeLoaded = true; 
                        misha_loadmore_params.current_page++;
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
```

**catloadmore.js - This one works on category.php AND front-page.php even though I'm not calling it on front-page.php. I just want it to work on category.php**

```
jQuery(function($){
    var canBeLoaded = true, 
    bottomOffset = 1300;

    $(window).scroll(function(){
        if ( cat_loadmore_params.current_page >= cat_loadmore_params.max_page ) {     
            return;
        }
        var data = {
            'action': 'loadmore',
            'query': cat_loadmore_params.posts,
            'page' : cat_loadmore_params.current_page
        };
        if( $(document).scrollTop() > ( $(document).height() - bottomOffset ) && canBeLoaded == true ){

            $.ajax({
                url : cat_loadmore_params.ajaxurl,
                data: data,
                type: 'POST',
                beforeSend: function( xhr ){
                    canBeLoaded = false;
                },
                success:function(data){
                    if( data ) {
                        $('#catfeed').find('div.catpost:last-of-type').after( data );
                        canBeLoaded = true;
                        cat_loadmore_params.current_page++;
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
```

**functions.php**

```
function misha_my_load_more_scripts() {
    if ( is_front_page() )
        {
            wp_register_script( 'my_loadmore', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/myloadmore.js',
            array( 'jquery' ), '', true );
            wp_enqueue_script( 'my_loadmore' );
        }
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'misha_my_load_more_scripts' );

function cat_load_more_scripts() {
    if ( is_category() )
        {
            wp_register_script( 'cat_loadmore', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/catloadmore.js',
            array( 'jquery' ), '', true );
            wp_enqueue_script( 'cat_loadmore' );
        }
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'cat_load_more_scripts' );


function register_my_session(){
    if( ! session_id() ) {
        session_start();
    }
}

add_action('init', 'register_my_session');

function cat_loadmore_ajax_handler() {
    $args = json_decode( wp_unslash( $_POST['query'] ), true );
    $args['paged'] = $_POST['page'] + 1; // load the next page

    $cat_query = new WP_Query( $args );

    if ( $cat_query->have_posts() ) :

        while ( $cat_query->have_posts() ) : $cat_query->the_post();

            $count = $_SESSION['count'];
            $_SESSION['count']=$_SESSION['count']+1;

            get_template_part( 'parts/categorycontent', get_post_format() );

        endwhile;
    endif;

    wp_die();
}
add_action( 'wp_ajax_loadmore', 'cat_loadmore_ajax_handler' );        // Authenticated users
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_loadmore', 'cat_loadmore_ajax_handler' ); // Non-authenticated users

function misha_loadmore_ajax_handler() {
    $args = json_decode( wp_unslash( $_POST['query'] ), true );
    $args['paged'] = $_POST['page'] + 1; // load the next page

    $the_query = new WP_Query( $args );

    if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) :

        while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post();
            $count = $_SESSION['count'];
            $_SESSION['count']=$_SESSION['count']+1;

            get_template_part( 'parts/content', get_post_format() );

            <?php if ($count == 8 && is_active_sidebar('seriesbar2') ) : ?>
                <div class="series-container post second-series">

                    <?php dynamic_sidebar('seriesbar2'); ?>

                </div>
            <?php endif;
        endwhile;
    endif;

    wp_die();
}
add_action( 'wp_ajax_loadmore', 'misha_loadmore_ajax_handler' );        // Authenticated users
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_loadmore', 'misha_loadmore_ajax_handler' ); // Non-authenticated users
```